# bun compatibility with nestjs?

Tags: nestjs, bun

I am currently having a project that uses nestjs and I was wondering how compatible is it with bun 1.0. I haven't found a clear answer on the internet and I don't want to transfer my project on bun just to end up on a dead end because of compatibility problems.

This is a small project that uses react and mongodb for the moment but I plan on using the built-in support of sqlite from bun.

I've already tried to use bun on the project and I can install the modules that I am currently using but I am scared of how far is it going. I haven't had the time to test everything so if I can get some info that would be nice.

Comment: Bun's 1.0 release blog post says it works with NestJS, but I am not too sure how to set it up. Maybe the NestJS team will come up with it in the docs in a while, but until then you could try starting a new simple project and tweak it to use Bun.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Update: It works now, except the build part. They are working on it. But I've got to say I'm becoming a fan of that developer's dedication.

Bun doesn't support `emitDecoratorMetadata` feature in typescript (yet?) which is required for NestJS because most dependency, pipes, guards all use Decorators in Nest. Also bun don't do type checking but that's an easy fix. Keep a watch on [this](https://github.com/oven-sh/bun/issues/1641) GH Issue. Maybe someone will work on it and provide a solution since Bun did show NestJS Logo on the video.

[image]

But if you just want faster reloads, [NestJS + SWC](https://docs.nestjs.com/recipes/swc) is pretty good.

Comment: thank you for the GH issue link, i can see that they haven't been fully transparent as they showed the nestjs logo in their presentation to show the compatible framework but apparently it is still a work in progress.

Comment: As of Bun version 1.0.3 `emitDecoratorMetadata` is supported.  Looks like you might be in luck.

https://bun.sh/blog/bun-v1.0.3

Comment: @Tamb Yup, Just checked it out. It works pretty good except the build part. And It seems the performance advantage for development at least is minimal ( I use nest with SWC so ). Maybe for runtime & live performance, it seems a superior runtime ( assuming RAM isn't an issue )